# I can not start the program Linux Graphics Debugger

Tags: linux, opengl, graphics

I want to use **[Linux Graphics Debugger](https://developer.nvidia.com/linux-graphics-debugger)** on my **Ubuntu MATE 16.04**

Starting with the parameters **`localhost`** port `**22**` but got error:

> `"Connection failed"`

[image]

However, I did as the  [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/linux-graphics-debugger/1.0/index.html) says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must mean that you cannot connect through `ssh`.  Do the following to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Then follow instructions.

Then to be sure you can test locally if `ssh` works properly:

```
ssh me@localhost
```

```
ju@ju-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:~$ ssh ju@localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 60:8e:2b:c2:6d:f8:b9:41:fa:ba:12:ae:a2:5b:30:a6.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ju@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-76-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

ju@ju-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:~$ echo there again
there again
```

Comment: Thank you all works before I was set OpensSSH package and I enjoyed them who knew that we needed access to the normal ssh